# Android TableLayout span with lines weights

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I would love to create a table layout of 
21 columns, 
- in the first column there is just one number
- the following 6 columns should each span 3 sub-columns
- from the 3 sub-columns one should have the double width

I tried it with weights and spans but the first row is way to wide :(
Does anyone have an idea?
It should look like :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7aPyXy2Vp8mTURaQmxQX2RNVFU/edit?usp=sharing
It looks like
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7aPyXy2Vp8mZ1YwSW9FRmNySVU/edit?usp=sharing

My code is this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#CCC"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:stretchColumns="0"
    android:id="@+id/tlTable01">

    <TableRow
        android:background="#CCC"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="R"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Farina"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Marieke"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Frank"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Jonas"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Nina"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Michel"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />


    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:background="#CCC"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Ce"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Ce"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Ce"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Ce"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Ce"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Ce"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Ce"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Ce"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Ce"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Ce"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Ce"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Ce"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Ce"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Ce"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Ce"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Ce"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Ce"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:text="Ce"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Here is the landscape version of the layout: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7aPyXy2Vp8mU191dVMzR1RDbUU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

- [image]

  ```
              <TableRow
                  android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:gravity="center" >

                  <Button
                      android:id="@+id/button1"
                      style="@style/box_sky_blue"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:text="1" />

                  <Button
                      android:id="@+id/button2"
                      style="@style/box_sky_blue"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:text="2" />

                  <Button
                      android:id="@+id/button3"
                      style="@style/box_sky_blue"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:text="3" />

                  <Button
                      android:id="@+id/button4"
                      style="@style/box_sky_blue"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:text="4" />
              </TableRow>

              <TableRow
                  android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:gravity="center" >

                  <Button
                      android:id="@+id/button5"
                      style="@style/box_sky_blue"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:text="5" />

                  <Button
                      android:id="@+id/button6"
                      style="@style/box_sky_blue"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:text="6" />

                  <Button
                      android:id="@+id/button7"
                      style="@style/box_sky_blue"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:text="7" />

                  <Button
                      android:id="@+id/button8"
                      style="@style/box_sky_blue"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:text="8" />
              </TableRow>

              <TableRow
                  android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:gravity="center" >

                  <Button
                      android:id="@+id/button9"
                      style="@style/box_sky_blue"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:text="9" />

                  <Button
                      android:id="@+id/button10"
                      style="@style/box_sky_blue"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:text="7" />

                  <Button
                      android:id="@+id/button11"
                      style="@style/box_sky_blue"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:text="8" />

                  <Button
                      android:id="@+id/button12"
                      style="@style/box_sky_blue"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:text="7" />
              </TableRow>

              <TableRow
                  android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:gravity="center" >

                  <Button
                      android:id="@+id/button13"
                      style="@style/box_sky_blue"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:text="9" />

                  <Button
                      android:id="@+id/button14"
                      style="@style/box_sky_blue"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:text="7" />

                  <Button
                      android:id="@+id/button15"
                      style="@style/box_sky_blue"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:text="8" />

                  <Button
                      android:id="@+id/button16"
                      style="@style/box_sky_blue"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:text="7" />
              </TableRow>
          </TableLayout>
  ```

here is box sky blue

```
<style name="box_sky_blue">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/box_color_sky_blue</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

I have square of 4x4,5x5 & 6x6

REGARDS
**maven**

Comment: hmm, I dont get how this helps with the spanning issue or the width of the first column